# iPhone SDK - UIActionSheet - Dynamic Button Titles

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a requirement in an application where I need to be able to add otherButtonTitles dynamically, dependent upon some BOOL switches that a user has specified in the settings.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to go about doing this in the UIActionSheet initialization.  I've tried to pass a NSString array (NSString[2]), and also a NSArray without any luck.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The easiest way to do this that I have found is initially create your action sheet with no buttons, including no cancel or destructive button:

```
UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Dynamic"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Then add a load of buttons as needed:

```
if(buttonX)
{
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button X"];
}
if(buttonY)
{
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button Y"];
}
if(buttonZ)
{
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button Z"];
}
```

Then finally add the cancel button at the end and set the cancel button index:

```
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = actionSheet.numberOfButtons - 1;
```

Of course you can add both a cancel button and/or a destructive button in this way.

Comment: @harrywynn, you should probably mark this as the answer (or one of them at least).

Comment: Note that cancel buttons don't show up where UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad. I spent 20 minutes trying to figure out why my button wouldn't show up after I set the cancelButtonIndex :)

Answer (score 6):

You can add new buttons to the (already initialized) UIActionSheet with `addButtonWithTitle:` method. You can also create your custom UIButtons and add them to UIActionSheet's view as a subViews

Comment: I had been using `addButtonWithTitle:`, then adding a "Cancel" button as the last one, using `setCancelButtonIndex` to identify it.  The problem is when you have more buttons than will fit on the screen, it switches to a UITableView, and the buttons become cells in the table.  If you don't have an actual Cancel button specified via `cancelButtonTitle`, there's no way to close the sheet because no button appears.  You have to exit the app at that point.

See these screens for an example:
http://conceptcache.com/tmp/with_cancel_button.png
http://conceptcache.com/tmp/without_cancel_button.png

Comment: That's strange - I've just created UIActionSheet with 20 buttons (added all of them with attButtonTitle: call). The sheet dismisses ok and both didDismissWithButtonIndex: and clickedButtonAtIndex: delegate methods get called... What version of sdk are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this by using some nil strings and an array.  I place the dynamic titles I need in an array, then loop through it and set the placeholder strings with as many titles as necessary.  The placeholder strings are then passed to `otherButtonTitles:` in the action sheet initialization.  Being `otherButtonTitles:` is terminated by nil, you can pass as many placeholder strings as necessary, as the first nil placeholder will terminate the rest.

```
// button titles    
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[buttons addObject:@"Button 1"];
[buttons addObject:@"Button 2"];

// placeholders
NSString *button0 = nil, *button1 = nil, *button2 = nil;

// put together the buttons
for (int x = 0; x < buttons.count; x++) {
    switch (x) {
        case 0:
            button0 = [buttons objectAtIndex:x];
            break;
        case 1:
            button1 = [buttons objectAtIndex:x];
            break;
        case 2:
            button2 = [buttons objectAtIndex:x];
            break;
    }
}

// action sheet
UIActionSheet *option = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:button0, button1, button2, nil];
```

Hope this is helpful to others facing a similar dilemma.

Comment: And what would you do if you need 20 or 30 buttons?

Comment: Well, I only need a max of 5, so this works for this particular application.  This probably wouldn't be practical if you needed 20 or 30.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that many buttons, create your own modal view and your own delegate protocol.

Check the documentation for `presentModalViewController:animated` and `dismissModalViewController:animated:`

When the user dismisses your modal view, your delegate can receive a method you build, something like `customActionSheetDidFinish:(int)buttonChosen`