# How to Change UIActionSheet Button title on their Click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

i am showing UIActionSheet on tapping of UIbutton.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clock" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Start",@"Reset",nil];
[actionSheet setTag:1001];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];

[actionSheet release];
```

I want to change the title of first "start" button  on clicking.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
    switch (buttonIndex) 
    {
        case 0:
        {
          // I want to change title of first button start to stop. on clicking.
        }
           break;
        case 1:
        {

        }
          break;
        default:
            break;
    }

 }
```

[image]

Need change start button title to stop and when it is stop again to start .Vice Versa

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: I edited question and my question is how to change title ?

Comment: And the "first" button is the first button in the action sheet, yes?

Comment: button at zero index sir .

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look like you can; `UIActionSheet` only provides a method to read the button title.  I would expect Apple felt it would be confusing if the button title changed once the action sheet had been displayed.

Comment: I don't think you are using the action sheet for the purpose it was intended; you should use another control.

Comment: See so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625470/iphone-sdk-uiactionsheet-dynamic-button-titles

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the text by using following code.
Try to implement in .m File

```
@interface AudioPlayerDemoViewController ()
{
UIActionSheet *action;
NSString *titleString;
}
@end

@implementation AudioPlayerDemoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    titleString = @"Start";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (IBAction)actionSheetTap:(id)sender
{
    action = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Demo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:titleString,@"Stop", nil];
    [action showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];

}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqual: @"Start"])
    {
        action = nil;
        titleString = @"Pause";

    }
    if([title isEqual: @"Pause"])
    {
        action = nil;
        titleString = @"Start";

    }

}
```

Comment: ya you are right , i was also thinking of something like this .Great.